# Personal Reputation League on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation-leagues

I don't know if this has been asked, but I can seem to find it. I was wondering if you could on Stack Overflow setup a **personal (i.e. non-public)** reputation league, that works on an invitation based system.

E.g. me and two programming buddies would like to quickly view which of us got the most reputation points during the course of a week or month, or any other period really.

I know you can still do that manually, but was just wondering.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: Because people disagree with your feature request. See [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work)

Comment: Why people down vote even after seeing something declined is beyond me, but don't take it personally - they just want to show that they wouldn't appreciate it if implemented (or reconsidered). Stack Overflow will soon have a meta site where you don't lose or gain rep, which will make this much less annoying.

Comment: Agreed with Tim, excellent idea but for build our own webapp. We can create some neat stuff with the API :) Dig into [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/) for plenty of inspiration, and if possible share yours with us; good luck!

Comment: Thank you @brasofilo, will go have a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The means to do this would be to [utilize our API](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-no-longer-beta/), which wouldn't be very difficult, quite a few people have done similar things.

I don't think this would work as a core feature because reputation alone is already a bit much when it comes to extrinsic motivation for some - adding more carrots at the end of the stick in a contest is definitely not going to help that.

Additionally, it creates moderator and support overhead if someone is thought to have 'cheated', and might encourage lesser quality contributions from those involved in a race to just try and win the race.

Still, it's not a bad idea, it's just something we'd rather see implemented by users themselves instead of as a core feature.

Comment: Execellent! Thank you. Would be better to manage it myself. I am working in a team, and trying to get people to upskill a little and by doing that help out the community. The incentive for them would be to have some sort of league that they can keep an eye on, and the winner could get something like a day off. The problem was that it would've been to public though.

Comment: @jacqijvv Don't forget to set up a key if you're going to be making a lot of requests (which would be needed for a more exciting 'real time' contest) and good luck! :) And wow, that's definitely a neat idea. If you see some stellar contributions come out of it, send me an email, I might be able to sweeten up the pot a bit.